# When does the Nginx error happen, recv() failed (110: Connection timed out) while proxying upgraded connection

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, websocket

I am using `Nginx 1.10.1` for my APP to balance connections on `Websocket`.

For example, the App `A`(multi-process) establish `Websocket` connections to `B1`, `B2` through `Nginx` so that the connections could be balanced.

While using it, sometimes even though my App send messages through the `Websocket`, the end-point(`B1` or `B2`) doesn't receive any message and after a while `Nginx` prints the error log message `recv() failed (110: Connection timed out) while proxying upgraded connection`.

The below is my config for `Nginx`.

Why does it happen and how to fix it ?
Something like connection timeout over network would lead this situation ?

```
worker_processes 2;
error_log /app_log/sangmin/nginx/error.log info;
pid /app_log/sangmin/nginx/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}
http {
            map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
                        default upgrade;
                        '' close;
            }
            client_body_buffer_size 5m;
            access_log /app_log/sangmin/nginx/access.log;

            upstream s2s_host{
                        hash $remote_port;
                        server 10.2.150.211:8080 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=10s;server 10.2.150.212:8080 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=10s;
            }
            server {
                        listen 10.2.14.195:10002;
                        location = /s2s {
                                    proxy_read_timeout 365h;
                                    proxy_send_timeout 365h;
                                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                                    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

                                    proxy_pass http://s2s_host;
                        }

            }
}
```